# SharePoint - Is it possible to achieve subqueries (SQL IN) with keywordqueries?

Tags: sharepoint, subquery, sql-in, keywordquery

I was wondering if it was possible to achieve subqueries with keywordqueries?

Something like this SQL query:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Production.Product
WHERE ProductSubcategoryID IN
    (SELECT ProductSubcategoryID
     FROM Production.ProductSubcategory
     WHERE Name = 'Wheels')
```

I don't think it's possible but as I don't know all the available options with keywordqueries (refiners, refinement filters,...), I prefer to ask.

Thanks for your help.
Bastien